# Races(time speed and distance)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> In a $2000$ m race between $A$ and $B$. $A$ gives $B$ a start of a minute but 
>   still beats him by $200$ m .When he increases the head start to 
>   $80$ seconds , the race ends in dead heat.Find the speed of $A$.

**options**

$a.)\quad 25\quad m/s\\
b.)\quad 18\quad m/s\\
c.)\quad 13.33\quad m/s\\
d.)\quad \color{green}{16.66\quad m/s}\\$

Let the $B's$ speed by $b$.
and let the $A's$ speed by $a$.

From the question i concluded the $b=\dfrac{200}{20}=10\quad m/s$

and I formed the equation

$\dfrac{2000}{a}=\dfrac{1800}{b}+60\\
\dfrac{2000}{a}=180+60\\
a=8.33\ldots m/s $

but it is not in options . Please tell where is my mistake.

Comment: The time that A is running is equal to the time that B is running MINUS 60 seconds, right?  so you need to subtract 60?

Comment: How do i exactly know that i need to add or substract $60$.

Comment: Your equation $\dfrac{2000}{a}=\dfrac{1800}{b}+60$ is a time equation.  You are saying, "Time A runs = Time B runs + 60 seconds"  But you know that B is the one that runs 60 more seconds because B is given the head start.  The time A is running is the entire time B is running, except for those first 60 seconds, when only B is running.

Comment: Or just see David K's answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's sometimes hard to know whether to add or subtract something.
It helps to make a clear model of how things compare.

In this case, you know that in the first race, B ran $1800$ meters 
in $\frac{1800}{b}$ seconds.
During the first $60$ seconds while B ran, A just stood waiting at the start line.
Then during the remaining time, A ran $2000$ meters.

So $60$ seconds plus A's running time is the amount of time 
B took to run the first $1800$ m in the first race.